# Update failed with 0x80010108 but most of my disk space is gone

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

I'm running Windows 10 version 1709, on a laptop that has been off for a year or more. I turned it on and let it download updates, only to see in update history

> Feature update to Windows 10, version 1803 x64 2019-10B (2)
>   Last failed install attempt on ‎21/‎10/‎2019 - 0x80010108

Windows has not notified me of any attempted or failed updates, I had to go and look. Meanwhile, I note I've lost about 8Gb of very limited disk space. Am I going to get this back? Is Windows going to notify me of the issue or just sit there pretending everything is fine?

Comment: Be sure date and time are correct then Try the Windows update troubleshooter shown here>>>https://www.thewindowsclub.com/fix-windows-update-error-0x80010108-on-windows-10

Comment: You can use the Disk Cleanup utility to recover the space.  Once you do that I would recommend using the Upgrade Assistant to go directly to 1903.

Comment: Windows needs 30 GB to upgrade (for Windows.old, install files and all else).  So it looks like you need to clear out 25 - 30 GB of space.